# Does Twemproxy / nutcracker support MGET command of Redis

Tags: redis, twemproxy

I am using nutcracker in my application to fetch data from Redis nodes.

Just wanted to know whether it supports multi get or it internally fetches all keys one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.
You can find all the Redis commands that twemproxy supports [here](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy/blob/master/notes/redis.md)